# What does the INK Deluxe Edition offer?

Tags: ink

I took a look at the Store Page for this new game called INK on Steam, and I've considered buying it when I have the chance.

However, when I go there, I see two different purchase options for it: the regular game, and a *Deluxe Edition* of sorts.

[image]

It's not advertised as a package containing the DLC, it doesn't specify what it contains, so I'm just wondering what it is.

**What does this 'Deluxe' Edition offer? Does it actually offer the DLC and I haven't realised?**

Comment: Alright, alright, I made a pretty stupid mistake this time with the question. Ugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [steam store page of the game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/385710/)

> Deluxe Edition
>
> The Deluxe Edition includes a copy of INK plus the Soundtrack + Art DLC all in one place!

Comment: Cripe, my bad. I didn't read it all.

Comment: The content of a deluxe version is almost always in the game description. I haven't found an exception to this rule anyway.